# Power supply for this cluster?

Tags: power-supply

I have this cluster, composed by:

- 1 Rpi4 Model B
- 2 Rpi3 Model B
- 1 Rpi3 Model B+

[image]

I don't neither the skills nor the tools/components to implement a DIY solution, so I would like to buy something that is ready to be purchased online. I've seen lots of Anker and UGreen power hubs, but their ports only deliver enough power when you don't use all the ports simultaneously, even the 100W devices.

Could you recommend me something that works OK, considering that I won't connect any other external device to the Pis' USB ports?

Thanks!

Comment: Product recommendation is not really a pert of this forum, but you can use multi-USB chargers like the Minix Neo P2 Turbo 4-Poorts 100W Charger or comparable. Be sure that you have sufficient power if you buy one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're insistent on not doing anything yourself just use 4 individual PSUs and a 4 way extension socket